# Max number of points to not beat the drop in a Soccer League?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say there are 20 teams in a soccer League and each team plays 2 games against any other team (one at home and one as a guest). A win is rewarded with 3 points, a draw is 1 point and loss is 0 points. At the end of the season the bottom 3 teams are relegated (and replaced with the best performing 3 teams from the lower level).

The question is, what is the max number of points to not beat a drop in a soccer league?

I saw a question here in [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329457/minimum-number-of-points-to-beat-the-drop-in-the-english-premier-league?rq=1), that the minimum number of points to beat the drop in the English Premier League is 64. So i think that the answer to my question is 63, because the min number of points to beat the drop must be higher by 1 point than the number of point to not beat the drop.

Is this logic correct?